# How to do that animation begins after page is fully loaded?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, keyframe

I have animation (`#svg_tag`, `.st0`). After animation complete, then fades-in the image (`.logo_svg`). I want that animation begins after page is fully loaded (both animation and image).

```
.logo_svg {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: show;
  animation-delay: 11s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
body{
  background-color: grey;
}
#svg_tag {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.st0 {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 1350;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1350;
  animation: draw 15s linear;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;

  }
}
@keyframes show {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

<body>

<svg version="1.1" id="svg_tag" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 708.7 437.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 708.7 437.3;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="XMLID_13_" class="st0" d="M708.7,285c-18.6,18.6-47.7,21.9-70,7.9v102.3l70,42V285z"/>
<path id="XMLID_12_" class="st0" d="M595.6,113.1l-113.1,67.9v7.5H509V245c0,16.6,13.4,30,30,30s30-13.4,30-30v-56.5h26.5v113.1
    h-26.5v-8.6c-9,5.6-19.4,8.6-30,8.6c-31.2,0-56.5-25.3-56.5-56.5v56.5l129.6,77.8V188.5h26.5v8.6c22.3-14,51.4-10.7,70,7.9v-24.1
    L595.6,113.1z"/>
<circle id="XMLID_11_" class="st0" cx="669" cy="245" r="30"/>
<path id="XMLID_10_" class="st0" d="M242.7,188.5h-9.9V245c0,25.7-20.9,46.6-46.6,46.6s-46.6-20.9-46.6-46.6v-56.5h-9.9V245
    c0,31.2,25.3,56.5,56.5,56.5c18.6,0,36.1-9.2,46.6-24.5v24.5h9.9V188.5z"/>
<polyline id="XMLID_9_" class="st0" points="279.2,188.5 259.3,188.5 259.3,198.4 269.2,198.4 269.2,301.6 279.2,301.6 279.2,188.5 
    "/>
<path id="XMLID_8_" class="st0" d="M259.3,123c0-5.5,4.4-9.9,9.9-9.9s9.9,4.4,9.9,9.9s-4.4,9.9-9.9,9.9S259.3,128.5,259.3,123
    L259.3,123z"/>
<rect id="XMLID_7_" x="295.7" y="113.1" class="st0" width="9.9" height="188.5"/>
<path id="XMLID_16_" class="st0" d="M425.4,0v213c-17.7-25.7-52.9-32.3-78.6-14.6c-25.7,17.7-32.3,52.9-14.6,78.6
    c17.7,25.7,52.9,32.3,78.6,14.6c5.7-3.9,10.7-8.9,14.6-14.6v24.5h9.9V0H425.4z M378.8,291.6c-25.7,0-46.6-20.9-46.6-46.6
    s20.9-46.6,46.6-46.6s46.6,20.9,46.6,46.6S404.5,291.6,378.8,291.6z"/>
<path id="XMLID_15_" class="st0" d="M103.1,213c-17.7-25.7-52.9-32.3-78.6-14.6c-5.7,3.9-10.7,8.9-14.6,14.6V0H0v301.6h9.9V277
    c17.7,25.7,52.9,32.3,78.6,14.6C114.3,273.9,120.8,238.7,103.1,213z M56.5,291.6c-25.7,0-46.6-20.9-46.6-46.6s20.9-46.6,46.6-46.6
    s46.6,20.9,46.6,46.6S82.3,291.6,56.5,291.6z"/>
</svg>

<img src="logo.png" class="logo_svg" alt="" />  

</body>
```

Comment: Hi Anvar, it's hard to understand your question without HTML code, that fits your problem. Can you post the HTML so we can test it out and find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for uploading the HTML.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you want to animate the logo, to draw itself, when the page loads. And then you want to animate another logo, that fades in.

If the logotypes are the same - then you can animate the first SVG logo itself, with one animation. No need for two :)

[Here's a little codepen](http://codepen.io/wicek3d/pen/xORKON) that does exactly that.

Here's the essential animation:

```
svg{
    max-width: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.st0 {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 1350;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1350;
  animation: draw 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes draw {
  95% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        fill-opacity:0;
        stroke-width:1;
  }
    100%{
        fill-opacity:1;
        stroke-width:0;
    }
}
```

Does this solve your problem?